# using IF condition to change imageview

Tags: android, json, string, imageview, android-adapter

this app will get get son from server. The value that I want to use is `categoryid`. you know clearly in the code below.

How can I use `categoryid` that from json to make condition to change imageview?

Hint: my ImageView is in `ImageAdapter` class

and I want to use condition that,

```
    if(catetgoryid == 1){
       imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1)
    } elseif (categoryid == 2 {
        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2)
    } else {
     imageview.setImageResorce(R.drawable.image3)
    }
```

JSON

```
{
"count": 54,
"data": [
    {
        "userid": "24",
        "cardid": "114",
        "title": "meeting now!",
        "carddate": "2012-12-26",
        "categoryid": "2",
        "cardimage": "http://xxx.xxx/data/card/thum/9589266f7983dbe72ff8481800f51ef9.jpg",
        "public": "1",
        "user": {
            "user_id": "24",
            "firstname": "kong",
            "lastname": "kea",
            "email": "xxx",
            "picture": "http://xxx.xxx/data/profiles/thum/default.png",
            "friend_status": "NOT_FRIEND"
        }
    }
]
```

}

MainActivity. this is MainActivity that get get json `categoryid`

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        String url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/card/all/30/0/?token=57LzEsmBeykLbDCD04wTgK9WWV2XjJY0XBdqVU0HQvjIdu5EtTWOT1IQ1AYNwxt6Q5bG6FG73uvzLQSDGAIezwc8VcopEp0s63uzbdVgLSfts0TLmuVDOgyfn4lX";
        JSONArray data = null;

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(getJSONUrl(url));

            MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
            HashMap<String, Object> map;
            data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                // Thumbnail Get ImageBitmap To Object
                map.put("cardimage", (String) c.getString("cardimage"));
                map.put("ImageThumBitmap",(Bitmap) loadBitmap(c.getString("cardimage")));

                map.put("categoryid",(String)c.getString("categoryid"));  // use it for condition 

                MyArrList.add(map);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Use condition here

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> MyArr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myArrList) {
        context = c;
        MyArr = myArrList;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return MyArr.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        }
            viewHolder.categoryCard = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_card);

            // ====================== use codition here ===============
            viewHolder.categoryCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_beauty);  
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        try {
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) MyArr.get(position).get("ImageThumBitmap"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
        }

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **getView()** method, try something like this. In the below method, you are sending the imageview along with the categoryid:
// Convert the category id to integer from String by using Integer.parseInt(categoryId); or you can compare with string itself in your if conditions like categoryId.equals("1"); and so on...

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
........................
...........................

viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
putDefaultImage(categoryid, viewHolder.imageView);
.............................
}

 private void putDefaultImage(int categoryid, ImageView imageview)
    {
         if(catetgoryid == 1){
       imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1)
    } elseif (categoryid == 2) {
        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2)
    } else {
     imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3)
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you briefly than this. I can us it as string but I want to use it as integer like you method `putDefaultImage`.

Comment: See this in my answer: int foo = Integer.parseInt(categoryId);// categoryId is string and foo is the int which was converted from string.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the 'catetgoryid' as a string, then doing an integer compare. Either add the integer conversion or change the if to a string comparison.

Comment: please can briefly than this?

Comment: `map.put("categoryid",(String)c.getString("categoryid"))` is inserting the string into categoryid, but `if(catetgoryid == 1)` is doing an integer compare.  If you converted the string to an integer I didnt see it.  So something like `if (Integer.parseInt(catetgoryid)==1`)...